# Does Broward County Transportation accept Miami Dade Transportation's 1-Day Pass?

Tags: usa, public-transport, florida, miami

I have to take the public transportation from the Miami International Airport to Miramar on a Monday, and I have to transfer from the Miami Metrorail to the Broward County bus. I am wondering if the Broward County Transport (BCT) accepts Miami-Dade Transportation (MDT)'s [one-day pass](https://transitstore.miamidade.gov/extern/products)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but the Day Pass for Broward is only $5.

Also, they use different fare cards so they couldn't offer coop service if they wanted to.

Comment: Can I purchase the BCT pass from the Miami airport?

Comment: I don't think so, but I've never tried.  MDT only has a machine I think, not even a booth.  If you're arriving at MIA, the best cheap option to Broward is Tri-Rail where you can transfer to BCT.

Answer (score 4):

In literally my first Google result, regarding [Broward County Transit fares and passes](http://www.broward.org/BCT/Fares/Pages/FaresPasses.aspx), there is a whole section covering transfers to and from other transit systems.

> TRANSFERS TO BCT FROM OTHER SOUTH FLORIDA TRANSIT SYSTEMS
>   When transferring from MDT, Palm Tran and Tri-Rail to BCT regular fixed-route bus service, passenger pays $.50 with a transfer issued by MDT or Palm Tran and proof of fare payment such as Easy Card and receipt issued by Tri-Rail. Tri-Rail passengers boarding BCT at any locations other than at a Tri-Rail station will be required to pay the full fare.
>
> TRANSFERS BETWEEN OTHER SOUTH FLORIDA TRANSIT SYSTEMS AND PREMIUM EXPRESS BUS SERVICE
>   [...]
>   Transfer from MDT or Tri-Rail to Premium Express Service, a $.50 transfer fee is required with the appropriate transfer from MDT or Tri-Rail.
>
> **The Easy Card issued by MDT and Tri-Rail is not accepted as payment on any BCT bus.**